# Can we pass closing bracket ")" at the end of a Url form View to Controller without using encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Can I pass closing bracket ")" at end of Url in Asp MVC.
I can pass it anywhere except at the end.
I have used many methods for it but helpless.

Comment: How are you exactly trying to pass it? you need to share the code. What problem you are facing?

Comment: http://example.com/AlzhUp%20(Reta%20Al%20Alzheimer%20S.L.) 
I want to pass it but the urls containing the closing bracket at the end are not passing.
If I place some character after closing bracket then its working fine.

Comment: You can encode the `)` using URL encoding..

Comment: But I don't want to encode it.
Any solution except encoding it.

Comment: *But I don't want to encode it. Any solution except encoding it.* - you should add that constraint to your question.

Comment: `example.com/AlzhUp%20(Reta%20Al%20Alzheimer%20S.L.)` would not be output as a link in any case. Please show what code you actually have in the razor template for outputting that link.

Answer (score -1):

Please try by encoding URL:

We can encode ) with **%29**.

Alternatively you can also try to escape the character with slash:

```
http://testurl\)
```

Comment: It is working by doing it.
But here I don't want to use encoding.
I want to use closing bracket in Url.

Comment: Did you tried with escape character? As I edited in my answer?

Comment: I tried it.
but this backward slash becomes forward slash after submitting it.
And gives error "Directory moved or not found like this."